# output multiple rows in php isn't working

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to output multiple rows from the database into an array, but it's only selecting the last row, how do i fix this?

```
$getSkills = $db->query("SELECT * FROM _skills WHERE `chara_id` = '$cid'");
    while ($skill = mysql_fetch_assoc($getSkills)) {
        $sid = $skill['id'];
        $sname = $skill['name'];
        $url = $skill['url'];
    }
    $data = array('skills' => array( '<img id="'.$sid.'" class="skill" src="'.$url.'">','<img id="'.$sid.'" class="skill" src="'.$url.'">','<img id="'.$sid.'" class="skill" src="'.$url.'">','<img id="'.$sid.'" class="skill" src="'.$url.'">' ));
<div class="skill_images"><img id="3" class="skill" src="/img/skills/5.png">
```

`

Comment: The `$data` part is not in the loop and as such will only get data from the last row.

Comment: youre using some oop method in the first line then a mysql_ function in the second line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to append to the array inside your loop.

```
$data['skills'] = array();
while ($skill = mysql_fetch_assoc($getSkills)) {
     $sid = $skill['id'];
     $sname = $skill['name'];
     $url = $skill['url'];
     $data['skills'][] = '<img id="'.$sid.'" class="skill" src="'.$url.'">';
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Because you are using the values of **$sid**, **$sname**, **$url** after the while loop has ended. This will always select the last row. If you want to select all the values in the row, declare the array inside the loop.